# MIPS prompt for a string and exchange the case of each character

Tags: mips

I am writing a MIPS program that prompts the user for a string and then parse the string exchanging the case of each character.
for example ->
Hey You becomes hEY yOU.
My question is, how do i make it do nothing if it encounters a space ? Any help would be great!

```
      .data

string4:.space      82              # space for input string

strPrompt:.asciiz   "Please enter a string: "

       .text
       .globl main

main:

    la  $a0, strPrompt      # print prompt
    li  $v0, 4
    syscall
    la  $a0, string4        # read string
    li  $a1, 80
    li  $v0, 8
    syscall

    la  $a0, string4        # print string
    li  $v0, 4
    syscall
    la  $t0, string4        # $t0 = &string4[0]
    li  $t1, 0

loop4:

    lb  $t1, 0($t0)
    nop
    nop
    beqz    $t1, done4      # if $t1 == NUL, we are done
    bgt $t1, 90, else       # if char > 90 its a lower case
    nop
    addi    $t1, $t1, 0x20      # if < 90 its upper case add 32
    sb  $t1, 0($t0)
    addi    $t0, $t0, 1     # add 1 to pointer
    j   loop4                   # jump back to loop
    nop

else:

    addi    $t1, $t1, -0x20
    sb  $t1, 0($t0)
    addi    $t0, $t0, 1
    j   loop4
    nop         

done4:
```

Comment: Make sure your code is indented 4 characters so it is properly formatted. That's what the **{ }** code button does.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a branchless way of changing the case of a character in `$t1` if it's in the range `A..Z` or `a..z`, and do nothing if it's outside that range:

```
# if (upper($t1) >= 'A' && upper($t1) <= 'Z') $t2 = 1; else $t2 = 0;
andi $t3,$t1,0xDF    # clear bit 5, if $t1 was an alphabetic character $t3 will now be uppercase
li $t2,'A'-1
sltu $t2,$t2,$t3
sltiu $t3,$t3,'Z'+1
and $t2,$t2,$t3

sll $t2,$t2,5      # $t2 = 0x20, or 0 
xor $t1,$t1,$t2  # either swap case or do nothing
```